# How to show $10^{2(n+1)}$ divided by $\underbrace{11\ldots1}_{n 1's}$ has a remainder of 100

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We know $10^n=9\times\underbrace{11\ldots1}_{n 1's}+1$,
$10^{n+1}=10^n\times 10$,
$10^{2(n+1)}=(10^n)^2\times 10^2$,
$10^{3(n+1)}=(10^n)^3\times 10^3$,

how could I show that if $10^{n+1}, 10^{2(n+1)}, 10^{3(n+1)}$ are divided by $\underbrace{11\ldots1}_{n 1's}$, we get the remainder $10, 100, 1000$ respectively?

I could do the $10^{n+1}$ as follow: $\frac{10^{n+1}}{\underbrace{11\ldots1}_{n 1's}}=\frac{10\times10^n}{\underbrace{11\ldots1}_{n 1's}}=\frac{(10\times9\times\underbrace{11\ldots1}_{n 1's}+10)}{\underbrace{11\ldots1}_{n 1's}}$ has the remainder $10$.

But if I tried using the same method as the above to do the $10^{2(n+1)}$ and $10^{3(n+1)}$, I could not show that the remainders are $100$ and $1000$ respectively? How could I do it, is there any other method? Are there any other alternatives?

Helps are greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you have been taught congruence arithmetic, this would probably be the easiest way to approach the problem.

Comment: For $n=2$, this seems to say that $10^3$ has a remainder of 10 when divided by 11, $10^6$ has a remainder of 100 when divided by 11, and $10^9$ has a remainder of 1000 when divided by 11.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ {\rm mod}\,\ m=(10^{\large n}\!-1)/9\!: \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\overbrace{\color{#c00}{10^{\large n}\equiv 1}}^{\Large 0\ \equiv\ 9m\, =\ 10^{\Large n}\ -\ 1\qquad\quad\ \ \ \ }\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\Rightarrow 10^{\large 2n+2} = (\color{#c00}{10^{\large n}})^2 10^2\equiv\, \color{#c00}{1}^2\cdot 10^2 \equiv\, 100$

Alternatively, without congruences
$$ m = {{{\overbrace{11\!\ldots\!11}^{\!\!\!\large n\rm\,\ ones}}} \,\mid\, \!\smash{\overbrace{\color{#c00}{10^{\large n}\!-1}}^{\large 9m\ =\ 99\ldots99\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}}\! \,\mid\, 10^2\, ((\color{#c00}{10^{\large n}})^2\color{#c00}{-1})\, =\,  10^{\large 2n+2}-100}$$

**Remark** $\ $ The proofs have been typeset in a way to highlight the relationship between both approaches. If you are learning congruences then it will be instructive to compare the two.